# Do ExpandableListView list item "press" behaviors have to be wired up by the developer?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, pressed

I have an Activity that uses a layout that contains a TextView, an ImageButton, and an ExpandableListView.  As far as I can tell, there are no default views for ExpandableListView's group and child views.  As such, the cursor adapter I provide to ExpandableListView is a subclass of CursorTreeAdapter that overrides newGroupView() and newChildView().  The group view contains a TextView and an ImageButton.  The child view contains a TextView and a RatingBar.

Is there anything special I need to do to (1) have the behavior where pressing a group item in the list causes the item's background to turn the default Android yellow/orange (2) have the group expand to show the children when the group item is pressed.

I thought these 2 behaviors were built into the ExpandableListView and didn't require any sort of special wiring up by the developer.  Is this incorrect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the problem was caused by having focusable views within my custom ExpandableListView group view.  It was further complicated by using an ImageButton.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919063/how-can-expandablelistviews-default-list-item-press-behavior-be-preserved-when-s) for a solution